# Spring - Change request Content-Type: text/plain to Content-Type: multipart/form-data in a Filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, request, multipartform-data

I’m using custom encryption to communicate front-end and back-end.

I’m trying to change the request Content-Type in a filter (Spring GenericFilterBean) before it reaches the controller.

To be more specific I want to change the request Content-Type: text/plain sent by front-end to Content-Type: multipart/form-data.

I made an infographic:
[image: infographic]

**CustomFilter.java**

```
public class CustomFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

...

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    // ORIGINALS
    HttpServletRequest originalRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse originalResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

    // DECRYPT REQUEST
    String bodyDecrypted = bodyDecrypted = decryptRequest(originalRequest); 

    CryptRequestWrapper wrappedRequest = new CryptRequestWrapper(originalRequest, bodyDecrypted.getBytes());
    CryptResponseWrapper wrappedResponse = new CryptResponseWrapper(originalResponse);


    // ---------------------------------------------//
    //           CHANGE CONTENT TYPE HERE?          //
    // ---------------------------------------------//


    // CHAIN
    chain.doFilter(wrappedRequest, wrappedResponse);
    
    // ENCRYPT RESPONSE
    String responseEncrypted = encryptResponse(vec, wrappedResponse); 
    response.getOutputStream().write(responseEncrypted.getBytes());

}

private String decryptRequest(HttpServletRequest originalRequest){
    // STUFF
}

private String encryptResponse(ModifyResponseBodyWrapper wrappedResponse){
    // STUFF
}
```

}

**CryptRequestWrapper.java**

```
public class CryptRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CryptRequestWrapper.class);

    private final ByteArrayInputStream decryptedDataBAIS;

    CryptRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request, byte[] decryptedData) {
        super(request);
        decryptedDataBAIS = new ByteArrayInputStream(decryptedData);

    }

    @Override
    public BufferedReader getReader() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(decryptedDataBAIS, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()));
    }

    @Override
    public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {

        return new ServletInputStream() {
            @Override
            public int read() {
                return decryptedDataBAIS.read();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isFinished() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isReady() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void setReadListener(ReadListener readListener) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        };

    }
}
```

**Question**

Its possible to do this? What I'm missing?

On the front-end side I tried to send a multipart request with body encrypted, but it's not working because the multipart request seems to need a "key/value" body. This is why i'm sending a text/plain.

Comment: encryption and decryption should be on the fly in your request wrapper, not in your filter.  Also you shouldn't really change the content type as that should already be the correct one. Fix the error you get (by properly encrypting/decrypting on the fly I would say).

Comment: @M.Deinum I don't get it, what do you mean “on my request wrapper”? TLS?

Comment: You are doing the encryption in your filter, however that should be part of the wrapper not your filter.